# How to convert this string from a list into binary?

Tags: python, binary, byte

I have this list of strings that I want to convert into binary, here is a snippet of the list:

```
b = ['\x1d\x04\x03\x1d\x06\x19R\x02\x0c\x05\x1c\x0c\x10\x1aST\x00\x16I\x02SB\x1a\x12\x04\n']
```

The list has several other strings like this one, I've been trying to iterate through the list but I keep getting the ASCII character to print out. I'm not sure what encoding this is in and is probably why I'm having trouble converting it.

```
for line in b:
    for char in line:
         print(char)
```

How can I convert this string into binary?

Comment: You don't have a list of bytes; you have a `str` that represents a sequence of Unicode code points. Where did you get this value? If it's hard-coded, use a `bytes` literal `b'...'` rather than a `str` literal `'...'`. If you read the data from some other source, that source is incorrectly providing you with a `str` object.

Comment: if the file is already in binary, you can open it in binary form with `open('file_path', 'rb')`.